# Texstudio bibliography - separate directory?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, texstudio, directory

I am writing to you as I did not find a solution or answer to this question, either on this site or others. Specifically, I am having troubles when using a separate directory for the biblio on Texstudio. Here is what I would like to do but just getting an undefined sequence in return:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}

The test is to cite \cite{Test2020}.

\bibliography{C:\Users\Name\Documents\folder\biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX always uses forward slashes to set paths, even for Windows. So write
`\bibliography{C:/Users/Name/Documents/folder/biblio}` and it should work.

Comment: It did, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to generate a shortcut of the biblio.bib file (right click the file --> Create shortcut) and to copy it into your project directory. You only need: `\bibliography{biblio}`.

This works fine for me because I can update my "root" bib file located elsewhere and bibtex.exe will find it through the shortcut.

A bit sloppy, but it does the job.

Hope this helps.

^..^